# Proof of $3^ns + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{n-k-1}2^{a_k}=2^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

How would I go about proving the following:

For any odd positive integer $s$, there exists a sequence of nonnegative integers $( a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1})$ and a nonnegative integer $m$ such that,

$$ 3^ns + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^{n-k-1}2^{a_k}=2^m.$$

I am really stuck. I was thinking of using the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^m}$ in a proof by contradiction, but I cannot even get started reducing the LHS to something simpler.

**Note 1:** I have reason to believe there exists such a sequence where

1. $a_0=0$
2. $\{a_n\}$ is strictly monotonically increasing

**Note 2:** I think an example might help.

$$ n=3 \quad \{a_n\} = [0, 2g-1, 2g+3] \quad s = \frac{5\times 4^g -2}{6} \quad m= 2g+5 \quad g >0$$

**Note 3:** The full example for $n=3$.

If $s$ is an odd positive integer such that its orbit contains exactly $3$ odd integers including $s$ and $1$ then $s$ has exactly one of two forms:

$$S = \frac{4^{3j+g} - 4^{g+1} -24}{72} \quad \text{ with } \quad a_{g,j}= \{ 0, 2g-1, 6j+2g-3 \} \quad g,j > 0$$

or

$$S = \frac{4^{3j+g+1} - 4^{g} -3}{3} \quad \text{ with } \quad a_{g,j}= \{ 0, 2g, 6j+2g+2 \} \quad g,j > 0.$$

Its possible to get the exact forms for bigger orbits in the sense that the orbits contain exactly $k$ odd numbers including $s$ and $1$, it just gets harder and more tedious. Also, this thing needs a proof.

---

Link to the question and some answers at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344904/7710)

Comment: Either there is a typo or I am missing something....  if $a_k$ is positive, then $2^{a_k}$ is even, then every term in the summation is even.  But $3^n s$ is odd, so $2^m$ must be odd, so $m=0$, so RHS $=2^m=1$ but LHS $\ge s$...?

Comment: You are correct. $a_k$ can be zero, I fixed the phrasing. For a moment I thought “positive integer” includes zero, but I updated the phrasing to be less ambiguous.

Comment: I am going to move this question to mathoverflow. Should I delete it from here?

Comment: I think MSE is the better place for this (disclaimer: I'm not working in professional math research)

Comment: Idon't know whether that tag meanwhile exists, but it should: "`exponential diophantine problems`". I would have seen that question immediately...

Comment: So what the OP is asking is a proof of the C.C.?

Comment: Looks like the *Collatz conjecture* ; if yes, then the OP is funny.

Comment: See also my answer at mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/345083/7710